# How to get the checkbox checked value in the save click event and save it in the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have checkbox in the gridview and a save button.....so far i have done to maintain the state of the checkbox in the pageindexchanging...in the save button click i want to save the values in which the checkbox is checked and save it in the database i need the code?

```
protected void ManageCalenderShift_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    StoreOldValue();
    EmployeeDetails.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    BindDataToGrid();
    PupulateoldCheckValue();
}
private void StoreOldValue()
{
    ArrayList categoryIDList = new ArrayList();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in EmployeeDetails.Rows)
    {
        Label can_id = (Label)row.FindControl("UserACENumber");
        bool result = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chkgrid")).Checked;

        // Check in the Session
        if (Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] != null)
            categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
        if (result)
        {
            if (!categoryIDList.Contains(can_id.Text))
                categoryIDList.Add(can_id.Text);
        }
        else
            categoryIDList.Remove(can_id.Text);
    }
    if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
        Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"] = categoryIDList;
}
private void PupulateoldCheckValue()
{
    ArrayList categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session["CHECKED_ITEMS"];
    if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in EmployeeDetails.Rows)
        {
            Label can_id = (Label)row.FindControl("UserACENumber");
            if (categoryIDList.Contains(can_id.Text))
            {
                CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("Chkgrid");
                myCheckBox.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in the save button click how to find the controls which is checked and save it in the database?

```
protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


foreach (GridViewRow row in EmployeeDetails.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkGrid = (CheckBox)EmployeeDetails.Rows[i].FindControl("chkGrid");
        if (chkGrid.Checked == true)
        {
            //There are two pages and four records in that i have checked the four records but controlis finding for the first two records in the first page if i use this code....
        }
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> string strIDs;
>
> string[] arrIDs;
>
> strIDs =
>   Request.Form["chkBox"].Replace("'",
>   "");
>
> arrIDs = strIDs.Split(',');

### Using request.form["CheckBoxID"] you got value of checkbox in gridview.

Comment: if you have more than one checkbox than take array.

Answer (score 0):

simply search for checkbox control with ID, u can find it by using Page.fincontol(control ID), chk the checked values by foreach, open connection and save in db. dont forge to close connection

Comment: I have used foreach in that gridview...But i am facing a issue...for eg if there are two pages in which two records are thr with checked,in the page1 only finding the control.....

Comment: "http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/69485/how-to-display-the-each-row-of-gridview-in-a-separ.aspx#answer3" chk this may b it can solve ur prob

Comment: try to cast vals in chk box and thn access thm using cheked property, this may help